# R - lrm logistic regression coefficients / odds ratio?

Tags: r

I am using the `lrm` function from the `rms` package to get:

```
> model_1 <- lrm(dependent_variable ~ var1+ var2 + var3, data = merged_dataset, na.action="na.delete")
> print(model_1)
Logistic Regression Model

 lrm(dependent_variable ~ var1+ var2 + var3, data = merged_dataset, na.action="na.delete")

                      Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test           Indexes           Indexes       
 Obs          6046    LR chi2     21.97    R2       0.005    C       0.531    
  0           3151    d.f.           11    g        0.138    Dxy     0.062    
  1           2895    Pr(> chi2) 0.0246    gr       1.148    gamma   0.062    
 max |deriv| 1e-13                         gp       0.034    tau-a   0.031    
                                           Brier    0.249                     

                            Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
 Intercept                  -0.0752 0.0348 -2.16  0.0305  
 var1                        10.6916 2.1476  0.32  0.7474  
 var2                       -0.1595 0.4125 -0.39  0.6990  
 var3                       -0.0563 0.0266 -2.12  0.0341
```

My question is are these coefficients odds ratios or not? If not, how can I get the odds ratios coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there here is an approach. Note that it helps if you include some sample data for us to work with.

Generating some fake data...

```
fake_data <- matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3)

y_start <- 1/(1+exp(-(fake_data %*% c(1, .3, 2))))

y <- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = y_start)

dat <- data.frame(y, fake_data)
```

Now we fit the model:

```
library(rms)

fit <- lrm(y ~ ., data = dat)
```

The model coefficients will be in the form of log-odds (still on the log scale)

```
# Log-odds
coef(fit)

 Intercept         X1         X2         X3 
0.03419513 0.92890297 0.48097414 1.86036897
```

If you want to move to odds then we need to use exponentiation to transfer from the log scale.

```
# Odds
exp(coef(fit))

Intercept        X1        X2        X3 
 1.034787  2.531730  1.617649  6.426107
```

So in this example you odds of achieving Y increases by 2.5 with an increase in X1.